# Oracle sql developer data type is unknown

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sql-data-modeler

When I want to add data types there is unknown,
win10 
Oracle SQL Developer 17.1

[image]

Comment: something 'looks wrong' with your install. you should have several dozen types listed there. Also, what version? There is no version 17.1. My version 18.1 looks good though.

Comment: The software is kind of don't need to install and I just unzip to run it.And when I run in another win10 PC  I could see all types, but the same thing when I put in this computer it doesn't work

Comment: Correct, i'm saying something went wrong with the unzip part. Try unzipping it into a fresh directory and try again. Also, there is no version 17.1, so i'm not sure what version you have to test myself here locally. Is it perhaps version 4.1 or 18.1?

Comment: actuality the version of Oracle SQL Developer is 17.4.0.355.2349. Maybe is something wrong with my os.

Comment: not an OS problem, one of the property files is borked. try downloading 18.1 and extract to a fresh directory, and try again. BTW i have 17.4 on Windows with Java 8 and it appears correct there for me as well

Comment: should say, 'appears correctly there' - as in, i think the software is fine, something happened to it between downloading and extracting it to your machine

Comment: Ok, I solve this problem by copy all setting and all films from the computer which hasn't this problem, thx you very much.:)

Comment: Cool! Ping us if you run into any more issues!